# Menu disappeared

Tags: interface

This issue seems to be specific to my OS(Win 10).On my previous laptop everything worked fine.Here the menu with the file with the 'file,render etc' options isn't available isn't visible.
And the window is as fully maximized as it could be.
[image: Screenshot of problem]
In the screenshot my mouse cursor isn't visible either.
Also the text, menu and stuff in the lowest portion isn't fully visible.
Kindly help.
Thanks.

[Please forgive my ignorance if I got any term wrong, I'm a new user.]

Answer (score 0):

You probably accidentally closed the "info window".

Here's what you can do:

- Create a new "window" (by dragging the top-right corner of any frame down or left)

[image: Interface to create a new window]

- On the window view selector (on the bottom-left corner of the "window"), select "info" from the dropdown.

[image: Window type selector]

- You can then select a new Layout and work from there

[image: Layout selector]

Comment: The layout is already in default.And there still seems to be a hidden window.Clicking on the info icon in the view selector doesn't seem to work unless in fullscreen.It seems glitchy.
Everything seems to work perfectly fine in fullscreen,tho.
I'll try updating the drivers, as indicated some other post then update if the issue was resolved.

Comment: Oh! I thought the problem was every time... Then, my answer does not apply.